# How do I create a search engine that find similar results in case it does not find a specific match? (mongoDB)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, search-engine

I am building a question function in my website where a user can search up a question
for example:
"how do I cook a cake?"
and get a link to the question someone else asked before of whom title is:
"how do I make a cake?"
the question is almost the same yet the writing is different and for now a user cant find question 2 if they search for question 1 search i just input the search bar into `collection.find({})`
how do I fix this? is there an API who can maybe generate similar and same meaning sentences to search for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this answer is a search engine tat you want but it is the best that mongodb can do.

Use [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

1. createIndex

```
db.articles.createIndex( { subject: "text" } )
```

2. data

```
db.articles.insertMany( [
     { _id: 1, subject: "coffee", author: "xyz", views: 50 },
     { _id: 2, subject: "Coffee Shopping", author: "efg", views: 5 },
     { _id: 3, subject: "Baking a cake", author: "abc", views: 90  },
     { _id: 4, subject: "baking", author: "xyz", views: 100 },
     { _id: 5, subject: "Café Con Leche", author: "abc", views: 200 },
     { _id: 6, subject: "Сырники", author: "jkl", views: 80 },
     { _id: 7, subject: "coffee and cream", author: "efg", views: 10 },
     { _id: 8, subject: "Cafe con Leche", author: "xyz", views: 10 }
] )
```

3. query

```
db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: "coffee" } } )
```

4. result

```
{ _id: 1, subject: 'coffee', author: 'xyz', views: 50 },
{ _id: 7, subject: 'coffee and cream', author: 'efg', views: 10 },
{ _id: 2, subject: 'Coffee Shopping', author: 'efg', views: 5 }
```

Comment: How would I find which subject does a topic/article/question belongs to? Should I try to split the string and then every word will be a subject? It will probably cause problems because all words will have the same importance in the query so it will find unrelated stuff.

Comment: @SweetWhite [Natural language processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) may be the first step

Comment: @SweetWhite [how-to-perform-full-text-search-in-mongodb](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-perform-full-text-search-in-mongodb)